# What user is the script run as after Carbon Copy Cloner ends scheduled task?

Tags: permissions, bash

On Mac OS X I keep data on a local server mirrored with the same data on a remote server with a scheduled backup task done with Carbon Copy Cloner.

After the backup is done a bash script is run as specified in the scheduled task options of CCC.

Is the script run as root?

Or differently and more generally: as my script writes to a log file, what command should I put on my script to see on the log if the script is running as root or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to put this in the script and have it echo out who the user is:

```
whoami
```

Or even something like this:

```
touch /tmp/testingfile
```

Then take a look at who owns /tmp/testingfile after the script runs.

Comment: thanks. shouldn't it be just "whoami" ? echo whoami outputs the string "whoami"

Comment: Yep you are correct, wrote that while under the influence of sleep deprivation. Edited

Answer (score 0):

As Regan suggested I put

```
whoami
```

in my script.

The answer is **yes** Carbon Copy Cloner runs the post-flight script as **root**